# How to find the relation between two time series data

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics, correlation

I have two time series data and I want to show the relation of them. The plot of two data looks like this:

[image]

From my point of view, when data2 stops changing, data1 also reduces changing amplitude. Also when data2 resumes sinusoidal movement, data1 resumes sinusoidal movement, plus a spike when it first time resumes. So I think there is some "relation" between this two data.

Is there any statistical test or model that can show my observation by my eyes? I've tried correlation and cross-correlation but neither of them gives me good result.

data1 is [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wgjy0X_m62akZvmwDreTNh_9F_mmCef-), data2 is [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mKcZ7jzhB7iH2aWltRCYlKAB0jHVBDY_).

I'm not a statistics student and I don't know whether I explain my question clearly, but any help would be appreciated!